# Get Size of All Folders in Directory

Tags: linux, find, du

I want to get the size of all directories within a specific directory. I was thinking something like

```
find . -type d -exec du -sh {} \;
```

But that returns all directories recursively.  How can I limit the depth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why use find at all and not simply glob for directories?

```
du -shc */
```

Comment: Well, the find option is more cross-platform, with the same command working on GNU/Linux and BSD/MacOSX systems (provided that `-maxdepth 1` is specified before the `-type d` argument). The OSX version of `du` will give a syntax error with  `du -shc */`.

Comment: Fair point, but do note that the poster used linux as a tag, so I was assuming linux in my answer.

Comment: This one is fine if you don't have hidden directories to include.

Comment: Easily adapted to hidden directories: `du -shc */ .??*/` (The ?? is to exclude . and ..)

Comment: This actually IS best on Linux, because it allows you to ignore the current working directory, only listing the subdirectories (what the OP specified). Find includes the `.` directory. It also gives you the choice to see the sum total or not.

Comment: Well, with -mindepth and -maxdepth find can exclude . too :)

Answer (score 7):

Add `-maxdepth 1` to your `find` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This one should do the job efficiently :

```
du -hc --max-depth=1
```

One big difference I think of is that, when encountering hardlinked files, they will be counted only once. In a find loop, they will be counted once per base directory. [Is it correct english?]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -maxdepth option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one,

```
ls | xargs du -sh
```

basically there are many ways to skin a cat :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
du -ah .
```

What it does is to take the subdirectories of the current directory, find its individual's size and in the end, it prints the total size.